# Applying a function using elements within a list

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I have what is hopefully a simple functional programming question. I have a list of locations with average temperature and amplitude for each day (180 days in my actual dataset). I want to iterate through these locations and create a sine curve of 24 points using a custom made function taking the average temperature and amplitude from each day within a list.

```
library(tibble)
library(REdaS)##degrees to radians
library(tidyverse)
data<- list(
  london = tibble(day =c(1,2,3),Average = c(1,3,2),
                Amplitude = c(2,5,6)),
                Glasgow = tibble(day = c(1,2,3),Average = c(1,2,3),
                       Amplitude = c(2,4,6)
))


sinefunc<- function(Amplitude,Average){
  hour<- seq(0,23,1)
  temperature<-vector("double",length = 24)
  
  for(i in seq_along(hour)){
    temperature[i]<- (Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*(hour[i]/24)))+Average)+Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*hour[i]/12))
  }
  temperature
}
```

I've tried using the map function in purr however have not quite mastered accessing the correct elements of the list for my function, and also had issues with storing the new created values.

Can anybody suggest a simple fix?

Many thanks,
Stuart
Edit to add my actual data structure:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So from my understanding, you have a list. So the simplest solution is to use `lapply` and itterate over every element of said list.

You first itterate over the list:

```
data <- lapply(data, function(x){
  sinefunc(Amplitude = x[,"Amplitude"], Average = x[,"Average"])
})
```

After that (and with some cleaning) you can use the data and plot your curve with `ggplot2`. Please keep in mind, that I extracted the location and written it to `loc`, as well as `day`, which both are used in the plot.
Following is the whole code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- lapply(data, function(x){
  sinefunc(Amplitude = x[,"Amplitude"], Average = x[,"Average"])
})
data <- data.frame(unlist(data))
data$loc <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", rownames(data))
data$day <- gsub("\\D", "", rownames(data))
ggplot(data, aes(x = day, y = unlist.data., color = loc, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: This looks like it will produce what i'm looking for. The error i'm getting on my main dataset is
```
 Error in x[, "Amplitude"] : incorrect number of dimensions 
```
Could this be due to the data actually being a nested format with amplitude and average within the tbl_df ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not tell. If your data is in another format, please provide that and I will change my answer

Comment: Added image to the main post, does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, would be better to paste a `dput` from your data. And if it's sensible, just change the values in the `dput` output

Comment: No worries, a dput would still be too large to paste given the character limit, even using a subset. I shall keep playing it with

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is this something you had in mind concerning `purrr`? I changed the example values a bit for the ggplot.

```
library(tibble)
library(REdaS)##degrees to radians
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

data<- list(
  london = tibble(day =c(1,2,3),Average = c(5,3,2),
                  Amplitude = c(5,5,6)),
  Glasgow = tibble(day = c(1,2,3),Average = c(1,2,20),
                   Amplitude = c(2,4,10)
  ))


sinefunc<- function(Amplitude,Average){
  hour<- seq(0,23,1)
  temperature<-vector("double",length = 24)
  
  for(i in seq_along(hour)){
    temperature[i]<- (Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*(hour[i]/24)))+Average)+Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*hour[i]/12))
  }
  temperature
}


data %>% 
  map_dfr(~sinefunc(.x$Average, .x$Amplitude)) %>% 
  mutate(day = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -day, names_to = "location", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = value, color = location)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: So it appears my reproducible code doesn't produce the same data structure as my actual dataset (images added to main post).  Your code returns "Error in .x$Average : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" as an error. Interested to know how to make this work with Purrr