# Applying a function using elements within a list take 2

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I attempted this question yesterday([Applying a function using elements within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748641/applying-a-function-using-elements-within-a-list/71748883?noredirect=1#comment126797333_71748883)) but my `reprex` produced the wrong data structure and unfortunately the suggestions didn't work for my actual dataset.

I have what is hopefully a simple functional programming question. I have a list of locations with average temperature and amplitude for each day (180 days in my actual dataset). I want to iterate through these locations and create a sine curve of 24 points using a custom made function taking the average temperature and amplitude from each day within a list. Below is my new `reprex`.

```
library(tibble)
library(REdaS)##degrees to radians
library(tidyverse)


sinefunc<- function(Amplitude,Average){
  hour<- seq(0,23,1)
  temperature<-vector("double",length = 24)
  
  for(i in seq_along(hour)){
    temperature[i]<- (Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*(hour[i]/24)))+Average)+Amplitude*sin(deg2rad(180*hour[i]/12))
  }
  temperature
}

data<- tibble(Location = c(rep("London",6),rep("Glasgow",6),rep("Dublin",6)),
              Day= rep(seq(1,6,1),3),
              Average = runif(18,0,20),
              Amplitude = runif(18,0,15))%>%
  nest_by(Location)
```

Using `Purrr` and `map_dfr` I get the error `Error in .x$Average : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

```
df<-data %>% 
  map_dfr(~sinefunc(.x$Average, .x$Amplitude))
```

Using `lapply` I get the error `Error in x[, "Amplitude"] : incorrect number of dimensions`

```
data <- lapply(data, function(x){
  sinefunc(Amplitude = x[,"Amplitude"], Average = x[,"Average"])
})
```

My goal is to have 24 hourly data points for each day and location.
Any further help would be much appreciated.
Stuart

Comment: Why do you use `map` / `lapply` instead of a simple `group_by` and `summarize`?
Anyway, your Problem is that `map` and `lapply` iterate over columns, not rows.

Comment: you can repurpose lapply to work like a for loop which is concise but wont bring much speed improvement by using `lapply(seq(nrow(data)), function(x){
  sinefunc(Amplitude = data[,"Amplitude"][x], Average = data[,"Average"][x])
}) ` not sure that is what you are looking for though

Comment: Am I right in saying ```summarize``` does not account for the extra space needed? i.e will only return the same number of values as ```length(data$location)```

Comment: @user12176714 The function that `summarize` calls has to output a single value, but the value can be a list of length 1, where the only element of the list is a vector of arbitrary length. You can then extract the list column to get a list of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you look for this? You get a dataframe back with 24 datapoints for each day and location, e.g. London-Day1, Dublin-Day1 etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data<- tibble(Location = c(rep("London",6),rep("Glasgow",6),rep("Dublin",6)),
              Day= rep(seq(1,6,1),3),
              Average = runif(18,0,20),
              Amplitude = runif(18,0,15))

# get group name
group_name <- data %>% 
  group_by(Location, Day) %>% 
  group_keys() %>%
  mutate(group_name = stringr::str_c(Location,"_",Day)) %>% 
  pull(group_name)


data %>% 
  # split into lists
  group_split(Location, Day) %>%
  # get list name
  setNames(group_name) %>% 
  # apply your function and get a dataframe back
  map_dfr(~sinefunc(.x$Average, .x$Amplitude))
```